# How can i sort datatable with my defined pattern in c#?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a datatable like this:

```
type             vol         id
-----------------------------------------
beam             120          9
foundation       340         12
column           80          20
```

and need to sort with type like this:

```
type             vol         id
-----------------------------------------
foundation       340         12
column           80          20
beam             120          9
```

How can I do this with defining "foundation" has precedence to "column", and "column" to "beam"?

Edit: For construction scheduling, it's important to find which element has precedence to other element, i want to create a method to sort rows(elements). Actually i want to define my pattern, for example if the type is "foundation", that row goes up!

Comment: Is it not just an aphabetical order in descending way?

Comment: @Steve no, i want to use a pattern for dynamic datatable

Comment: How can I do this? Well, by writing some code maybe? We´re not here to do that for you, you have to provide some own ideas.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ok

Comment: Please explain your problem better because it is not clear what do you mean with _dynamic datatable_ and what is a _pattern_ in this context

Comment: what is the pattern, your example does not make sense to me

Comment: The pattern is like this: "foundation" has precedence to "column", and "column" to "beam"

Comment: Are you trying to make a sort order by type descending? I mean starting from Z and ending in A

Comment: On what is your sorting based exactly? try to be more specific.
For example, do you want to sort them based on alphabetical order or based on their ID etc.

Comment: actually i want to define my pattern, for example if the type is "foundation", that row goes up!

Comment: This is clearly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  It appears the OP wants to implement some kind of priority based scheduling with a naive sort instead of the requisite PERT/GANTT logic.  A simple "precedence" based approach is going to fail as soon as it is realized that dependencies may not be linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a custom `IComparer<T>` which compares two items based on their position within a reference order that you define.  Then, use the comparer to sort the rows of your table.

```
public class PrecedenceComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private List<T> ReferenceList { get; set; }

    public PrecedenceComparer(IEnumerable<T> referenceOrder)
    {
        if (referenceOrder == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(referenceOrder));

        ReferenceList = referenceOrder.ToList();
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        int xIndex = ReferenceList.IndexOf(x);
        int yIndex = ReferenceList.IndexOf(y);
        if (xIndex >= 0 && yIndex >= 0) return xIndex - yIndex;
        if (xIndex >= 0) return -1;
        if (yIndex >= 0) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to sort a `DataTable` in place using a comparer, so you'd need to get the rows from the table, sort them using the comparer and then copy the sorted rows into a new table, like this:

```
public static DataTable SortTable(DataTable table)
{
    var comparer = new PrecedenceComparer<string>(new string[] { "foundation", "column", "beam" });

    // sort the rows of the original table
    var orderedRows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .OrderBy(row => (string)row["type"], comparer)
        .ThenBy(row => (int)row["vol"])   // secondary sort (delete this line if there isn't one)
        ;

    // copy the sorted data to a new table
    DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        newTable.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in orderedRows)
    {
        DataRow newRow = newTable.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            newRow[i] = row[i];
        }
        newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    return newTable;
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R5ypUo

Answer (score 0):

Usually the approach to use here would be to have a hidden column that isn't shown, but is the `precedence` - probably being derived from the `type`. So the real table would be:

```
type             precedence    vol         id
----------------------------------------------
foundation       12            340         12
column           400           80          20
beam             801           120          9
```

Alternatively, if `type` is an object, you could do it via a custom compare operation:

```
public class StructureType : IComparable, IComparable<StructureType> {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Precendence {get;set;}
    public override string ToString() => Name;
    public int CompareTo(StructureType other)
        => other != null ? Precendence.CompareTo(other.Precendence) : -1;
    int IComparable.CompareTo(object other)
        => other is StructureType st ? CompareTo(st) : -1;
}
```